# Allow height% with jQuery scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, jscrollbar

I am using the [Malihu custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) with automatic scrolling. So far, I basically am experimenting with it. I noticed when I take the height of the scrolling div and use a percentage instead of a fixed amount in px, it expands the div the entire height of the scroll area (off the screen).

I'm literally just taking the code from [this GitHub location](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin) then opening the file "auto_scrolling_example.html".

Then in the `<style>` section of the header, I'm simply changing `.content: height:500px` to `.content: height:50%`.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work and/or have a good workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the height or width as a percentage, that's a percentage with respect to the element's parent.

If the parent doesn't have any height or width inner children will not work in percentage.

Comment: This still occurred when I had `body { height: 100%}`. Does it need to be another div, or?

Comment: body height should be in `px` the inner divs can be in percentage